# How to proxy_pass x-access-token (JWT) header in nginx?

Tags: http, nginx, jwt, nginx-reverse-proxy

I am trying to use nginx as a reverse proxy, but I couldn't find anything on how to forward the x-access-token (JWT) header.

The reverse proxy works fine, and using `http://localhost/app` gives me the api. However, when I try to access anything requiring a token, ex. `http://localhost/app/api/products` I get `Cannot GET //api/products`.

In the documentation, it says that the default is `proxy_pass_request_headers on;` but the problem doesn't seem to be there.

**nginx.conf**

```
events {}

http {
    server {
        listen 8000;

        location /app {
            proxy_pass 'http://localhost:3000/';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you confirm what headers your api is getting?

Comment: @ShawnC. It turned out that the problem was with the trailing slash at the end of the proxy_pass. Without it, I can access the app. However, it is advised to use the slash, but I can't access it then.